# How to give focus-visible to all elements in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following my tailwind project:

```css
:focus-visible {
  outline: var(--primary-color) auto 2px;
}
```

Today I discovered the [`focus-visible` utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#focus-visible). When I set this class to one element it does have the correct selection. However I have to set it to all selectable elements. Is there a way to set for example one class to the body and all children get this property? Or do I have to use the custom css file?

When I set the focus-visible to the body the children do not inherit this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [arbitrary variant class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) on the `<body>`:

```html
<body class="[&_:focus-visible]:class-name">
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to find this but learned it now! :)